# Why is my FileStream path being changed to include the path of my code?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, filestream

OK so I use this code:

```
FileStream FS;
StreamWriter SW;
FS = new FileStream(path: newFileName, mode: FileMode.Append);
SW = new StreamWriter(FS);
SW.WriteLine(message);
SW.Close();
SW.Dispose();
FS.Close();
FS.Dispose();
```

And when run the file 
The path to the code is included with the newFileName. Why? is it a setting in vs? what am I missing? it used to work.

To be clear the line where this is happening is:

```
FS = new FileStream(path: newFileName, mode: FileMode.Append);
```

Comment: What is the value of `newFileName`?

Comment: And where is newFileName declared and set?

Comment: Is filename a relative path?

Comment: FileStream is not changing the path, where does the code construct/set newFileName?

Comment: Can you please post the code for the method in full?

Comment: Strings are immutable, it cannot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `newFileName` is a relative path. Check your working directory in the project settings. The issue is how the code is setting `newFileName`.